# How to upload encrypted data to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3, file-upload, botocore

I am trying to upload encrypted data to S3.  This code successfully encrypts the data, however it uploads the original unencrypted file to S3.  How do I tell it to upload the encrypted data instead?

note-the commented decryption lines were to test the data had been encrypted and decrypted properly

```
session = botocore.session.get_session()
client = session.create_client('kms', 
                               region_name = 'us-east-1', 
                               aws_access_key_id = '[YOUR ACCESS KEY]', 
                               aws_secret_access_key = '[YOUR SECRET ACCESSKEY]')

key_id = '[KEY ID]'
plaintext='[FILEPATH\FILENAME.CSV]'



ciphertext = client.encrypt(KeyId=key_id, Plaintext=plaintext)
#decrypt_ciphertext = client.decrypt(CiphertextBlob = 
ciphertext['CiphertextBlob'])
print('Ciphertext: ', ciphertext)
#print('Decrypted Ciphertext: ', decrypt_ciphertext) 


s3 = boto3.client('s3',
         aws_access_key_id='[YOUR ACCESS KEY]',
         aws_secret_access_key='[YOUR SECRET ACCESS KEY]')

filename = '[FILEPATH\FILENAME.CSV]'
bucket_name = '[BUCKET NAME]'

# Uploads the given file using a managed uploader, which will split up large
# files automatically and upload parts in parallel.
s3.upload_file(filename, bucket_name, filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [KMS `encrypt()` command](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/kms.html#KMS.Client.encrypt) does *not* work on files. Rather, it accepts incoming text in `Plaintext` and outputs encrypted text in `CiphertextBlob`.

Your code is responsible for reading the source file and passing the contents to `encrypt()`, and it is then responsible for writing the contents out to disk.

See also:

- [AWS Encryption SDK for Python Example Code - AWS Encryption SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/python-example-code.html)
- [s3-client-side-encryption/put.py at master · tedder/s3-client-side-encryption · GitHub](https://github.com/tedder/s3-client-side-encryption/blob/master/put.py)